# Equilibrium point $X_0$: $\dot{X}\mid_{X_0}=AX_0^{T}$, where $A$ has a zero eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I am studying equilibrium points of systems of ODEs and have a doubt:

I have the system $\dot{X}=F(X,t)$ and know the equilibrium point $X_0$. I have $\dot{X}\mid_{X_0}=AX_0^{T}$ and $A$ has an eigenvalue zero and the other is $\lambda$.
An author classifies the equilibrium point $X_0$ of $\dot{X}=F(X,t)$ as unstable if $\lambda>0$ and stable if $\lambda<0$. 
What is the mathematical basis of this affirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least partially wrong.

A fixed point whose Jacobian (your $A$ in my understanding) has one zero eigenvalue is called *marginal.* Such fixed points are never stable, even if the other eigenvalue ($λ$) is negative.

The simplest example is the dynamics of a ball in a one-dimensional potential $V$ without friction. Suppose the potential (not the dynamics) has a saddle point of the potential, i.e., a point with $V'=0$, $V''=0$, and $V'''≠0$. The ball being at rest at this point is a fixed point of the dynamics. The Jacobian has one zero and one negative eigenvalue. However, this fixed point is not stable as almost all trajectories in the vicinity do not converge to it: The ball needs to have exactly the right energy to come to rest at the point. Instead the trajectories are parallel to the fixed point in phase space, which is a hallmark of a marginal fixed point.

If $λ>0$, you have indeed an unstable, marginal fixed point. This can be seen as follows: Almost every small displacement from the fixed point has some component along the direction of the eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue. This component will dominate the dynamics in the vicinity of the fixed point. Thus almost every trajectory in the vicinity of the fixed point will lead away from it.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!! I am reading a little bit more about marginally stable point, in Wiki "A homogeneous continuous linear time-invariant system is marginally stable if and only if the real part of every pole (eigenvalue) in the system's transfer-function is non-positive, one or more poles have zero real part and non-zero imaginary part, and all poles with zero real part are simple roots (i.e. the poles on the imaginary axis are all distinct from one another). ... If one or more poles have positive real parts, the system is unstable".

Comment: I confess I did not could understand your example (because this is my first time on ODE theory). Please sorry, but thanks anyway!!